# Magento 2 : Deprecated Functionality: Function ReflectionType::__toString() is deprecated

Tags: magento2

When I try to execute bin/Magento setup:install from command line I get an exception as "Deprecated Functionality: Function ReflectionType::__toString() is deprecated".
It gives the same error for my previous Magento instance when I do

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

It was running all good a few days earlier.

Any solution for this?

**Note**: I am using PHP 7.4 on my machine and installed Magento 2.3

Thank You

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: Hello @Smita Kagwade i am not sure but try this your all command use your php version ex:- `php74 bin/magento c:c` check this link --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60437067/11908692

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Magento 2.3 is not compatible with Php 7.4, So there are two possible solutions:

1. Downgrade you Php version to 7.3 - **Recommended**
2. If it is not possible for you to downgrade php version, you need to perform few changes in core files. ***This is a work around until Magento get compatible version for Php 7.4***. When installing on my end I had faced few issues, this is what I did.

**Change 1:**

> File:
> vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Reflection/ParameterReflection.php

In function `detectType()` replace line `return (string) $type;` with `return $type->getName();`

**Change 2:**

> Error: Deprecated Functionality: implode(): Passing glue string after
> array is deprecated
>
> File: vendor/magento/framework/DB/Sql/UnionExpression.php

In function `__toString()` replace line `$sql = implode($parts, $this->type);` with `$sql = implode($this->type,$parts);`

**Change 3:**

> File: vendor/magento/framework/App/AreaList.php

In function `getCodeByFrontName()` replace line `if ($areaInfo['frontName'] == $frontName)` with `if (isset($areaInfo) && $areaInfo['frontName'] == $frontName)`

Hope you will find it helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Abdul Pathan 
Thanks For this:)

Comment: Thanks thats work for me (y)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it resolved all errors we got after upgrade to php 7.4 in magento 2.3.5 however we are now getting 404 on all product detail pages, do you know any workaround for that?

Comment: I still get the error even after downgrading to php 7.33.3

Answer (score 6):

One more change in message queue batch consumer file if needed

> Deprecated Functionality: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ?: d` is
> deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ?: d` or `a ? b : (c ?: d)` in /
> vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/BatchConsumer.php on line 154

Before:

```
$count = $maxNumberOfMessages
            ? $maxNumberOfMessages
            : $this->configuration->getMaxMessages() ?: 1;
```

After:

```
$count = ($maxNumberOfMessages
            ? $maxNumberOfMessages
            : $this->configuration->getMaxMessages()) ?: 1;
```

Ref. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/MessageQueue/BatchConsumer.php#L154

Answer (score 1):

I had Got same ""Deprecated Functionality: Function ReflectionType::__toString() is deprecated" when i was installing magento2.3.6 on php7.4.

I had did some more changes in magento vendor module as above @abdul defined for work in staging server.

**File 1: vendor/laminas/laminas-code/src/Reflection/ParameterReflection.php** file

Change detectType function if condition where return type is converted in string. I had remove string

```
if (method_exists($this, 'getType')
        && ($type = $this->getType())
        && $type->isBuiltin()
    ) {
        return $type->getName();
    }
```

**File 2: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Sortby.php**

i was changed beforeSave function. updated ternary operator there.

find in beforeSave function.

```
$attributeValue = is_array($data) ? reset($data) :
                (!empty($data)) ? $data : null;
```

To

```
$attributeValue = (is_array($data) ? reset($data) :
                (!empty($data))) ? $data : null;
```

File 3: **vendor/magento/framework/App/AreaList.php**

change in public function getCodeByFrontName($frontName) function

find

> if ($areaInfo['frontName'] === $frontName) {

And Replace it with

> if (isset($areaInfo) && $areaInfo['frontName'] == $frontName) {

As above @abdul describe.

After i had execute successfully "setup:upgrade" and "Static-content:deploy -f" command.